# Why has the cyclical import issue disappeared?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

There is an obvious cyclical import error when importing this package:

File `__init__.py`:

```
from . import modules
```

File `forward.py`:

```
from .modules import ext_modules

def forward(dest):
    if dest in ext_modules:
        print("forwarding to {}".format(ext_modules[dest]))
```

File `modules.py`:

```
from . import forward

ext_modules = {}

def main():
    ext_modules['test'] = 'TEST'
    forward.forward('test')
```

This import problem can be solved e.g. by exchanging lines 1 and 3 in the modules.py file. So far I think I understand what is going on.

What I really do not understand is this. When I add another import to the top of the `__init__.py` file:

```
from . import forward
from . import modules
```

the problem is gone. The package can be imported and the main function works. However the cycle dependency between `modules` and `forward` is still there. These files are left unmodified. Could you please explain me what is going on there? (Python version 3.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that happens when you import a module, is that an *empty* `module` object is added to the `sys.modules` mapping. Subsequent `import` statements for that same module will re-use that object rather than load the file into memory.

Python then proceeds to execute the module contents and add the global names this produces to that `module` object.

In your case, it matters what *order* your modules are imported. `forward` directly depends on the *module contents* of `modules`, while `modules` only depends on the module `forward` to exist, not the contents of that module (the `forward.forward` reference dependency is postponed until `main()` is called).

So if `forward` is imported first, the empty `forward` `module` object is created, the first line `from .modules import ext_modules` is executed, triggering the the `modules.py` file to be loaded, which then can *safely* use `from . import forward` because that *empty* `module` object now exists. The rest of the `modules.py` file can then continue to run without further incident.

But if you import `modules` first, then there is no `forward` `module` object yet, so then the `forward.py` file is run second, and the `from .modules import ext_modules` line fails because the `modules` `module` object is still empty and has no `ext_modules` attribute.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I have discovered it by a coincidence. I'm not sure how to call it. An "empty module trick" perhaps? Anyway, would you recommend to use it as a possible solution to the cyclical dependency problem or is it rather an ugly hack?

Comment: @VPfB: it is a proper solution to your problem. You could improve on it by using `from . import modules` in `forward.py`, then use `modules.ext_modules` in the `forward(dest)` module; i.e. use late binding everywhere.